NetBSD 10.0 install on HP EliteBook 8570w fails with breakpoint error during boot
I am trying to install, for the first time, NetBSD-10.0-amd64 on HP EliteBook 8570w. After choosing "Install BSD" option installer goes to the booting mode and gets interrupted with an error:
502c0
Stopped in pid 294.294 (init) at            netbsd:breakpoint+0x5: leave
breakpoint() at netbsd:breakpoint+0x5
vpanic() at netbsd:vpanic+0x183
panic() at netbsd:panic+0x3c
cnopen() at netbsd:cnopen+0x104
cdev_open() at netbsd:cdev_open+0x12a
spec_open() at netbsd:spec_open+0x1e0
VOP_OPEN() at netbsd:VOP_OPEN+0x3e
vn_open() at netbsd:vn_open+0x2ec
do_open() at netbsd:do_open+0xc3
do_sys_openat() at netbsd:do_sys_openat+0x74
sys_open() at netbsd:sys_open+0x24
syscall() at netbsd:syscall+0x1fc
--- syscall (number 5) ---
netbsd:syscall+0x1fc
ds            8
es            2
fs            180
gs            4a80
rdi           0
rsi           ffffffff81d88000
rsi           ffffbe8345a54ad0
rbx           0
rdx           1
rcx           ffffffffffffff
rax           800000000000000
r8            0
r9            0
r10           ffffffff818450e0      x86_mem
r11           fffffffe
r12           ffffffff8139af6f      ostype+0x13aa
r13           ffffbe8345a54b18
r14           104
r15           ffff8046d2cbdbc0
rip           ffffffff80235385      breakpoint+0x5
cs            8
rflags        202
rsp           ffffbe8345a54ad0
ss            10
netbsd:breakpoint +0x5: leave

If I continue the system precedes to reboot.
I'm not familiar with bsd tools so please tell me if I left important information.
Notice
I installed FreeBSD and Arch Linux on the same machine and it worked fine.

Does NetBSD have a disk formatting software bundled with installer? Maybe the memory problem occur when it tries to write to a disk which is already used?

Unfortunately it looks like the actual error message has scrolled off the screen.  There should have been a panic message just before the lines above as it looks like cnopen() called panic() while trying to open the console device.  I'd guess that message would be "cnopen: no console device".  If I had to guess I'd say the DRM driver is causing problems with basic "vga" console support.  Interrupt the bootloader, at the boot prompt type boot -c, at the uc> prompt type disable i915krmkms then quit. See https://wiki.netbsd.org/tutorials/x11/how_to_use_wsfb_uefi_bios_framebuffer/#index4h2
